# PHP: Displaying data from Bigcommerce API

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I am trying to display the data from Bigcommerce through php when I run the Bigcommerce::getCategories() i getting a array of data like this:

```
[0] => Bigcommerce\Api\Resources\Category Object
        (
            [ignoreOnCreate:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => id
                    [1] => parent_category_list
                )

            [ignoreOnUpdate:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => id
                    [1] => parent_category_list
                )

            [fields:protected] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 88
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [name] => Dell
                    [description] => 
                    [sort_order] => 0
                    [page_title] => 
                    [meta_keywords] => 
                    [meta_description] => 
                    [layout_file] => 
                    [parent_category_list] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 88
                        )

                    [image_file] => 
                    [is_visible] => 1
                    [search_keywords] => 
                    [url] => /dell/
                )

            [id:protected] => 88
            [ignoreIfZero:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [fieldMap:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )
```

but when I try to pass this to JQuery so that I can display it using this statement: `<?php echo json_encode($categories); ?>` I am getting an array of empty objects, what is the right way to get the array of objects in Bigcommerce API? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the first line of your  code:

`[0] => Bigcommerce\Api\Resources\Category Object`

You have an object, not an array. Try casting it to an array first:

```
$array =  (array) $yourObject;
```

Comment: yup, this should work, but not for the reason you think. json_encode is fully capable of encoding objects (whilst you seem to believe that json_encode can't encode object, it can). but it won't encode `protected` properties of objects, which all his object's arrays are. when you cast it to an array, you take away the `protected` properties completely, because php's arrays doesn't have a concept of visibility.